# How to access mysql database from godaddy in ipage as ipage have blocked remote access

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, shared-hosting

I have asked ipage to allow remote access but it was been told that they never allow remote access to take place. So can any one help is there any other way to access my MySQl data base from Godaddy hosting from ipage.

If possible I can even have the database in ipage but the issue is since the remote access been blocked the database can't be sent to Godaddy even.

Kindly help me whether there is any other way.

Comment: Why can't you send the database to GoDaddy? I don't know ipage, but I am 100% sure that you can, like with any other hoster, login to some page (like phpmyadmin, wordpress backup) or ssh that would allow you to do a backup, download that file and upload it to godaddy. No remote access to mysql means that you can't directly access the db from the outside, not that you can't use it at all (from the inside after a login to their systems or anything that runs on their systems). Unless blocked remote access means your account has been frozen completely for e.g. payment or security reasons.

Comment: Thank you  Solarflare for your reply. But the real part is I planned to access godaddy database from ipage but it seems usually they have blocked all remote access of ipage in shared hosting and thats why searching for any other way to make it.

Comment: I guess you get what you pay for. Blocking remote access TO a database is a standard configuration - can you really access godaddy-mysql from e.g. your home? They might not allow it either. And it might make sense ipage doesn't allow you to share databases with other hosters; why would they, you could just buy it all from them, and if you are so big you really need distributed systems, you don't use shared hosting or budget hosters at all. But you asked for a way to copy your database from godaddy to ipage. There is no way they don't allow you to upload or download a mysql dump in some way!

Answer (score 0):

iPage does not support remote database connection in their shared hosting platform. It's supported in their VPS and Dedicated server hosting. It is better to keep everything in one place.